# Overriding 'package' member functions in D

Tags: d, dmd

I have a member function in a class with the `package` [protection attribute](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#ProtectionAttribute) and I want to override it in a subclass, in the same package, different module. The dmd compiler shouts that I cannot override a non-virtual function. If I make the function `public`, it actually works.

Why a package function is not virtual?

Example code:

```
module test.A;
class A {
  package void doSomething() {}
}

module test.B;
import test.A;
class B : A {
  package override void doSomething() {} // ERROR! overriding a non-virtual function
}
```

Comment: From what I see, B is not a subclass...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the example. B is a subclass, I'll fix it. And `protected` does work, but I need it to be `package`, hehe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public` and `protected` functions are always virtual unless the compiler decides that it can optimize them so that they're non-virtual (which can only happen if you mark them as `final`, and they don't override anything). Some specific calls to virtual functions might be optimized to non-virtual if the compiler can guarantee the exact type of the object, but that's not likely to happen often given that it's relatively rare that you can know the exact type of an object (generally only right after creating it with `new`), and dmd generally eschews flow analysis.

`private` and `package` are never virtual.

The online documentation *does* imply that you can overload `package`, but this is definitely not what the compiler does, and I'm 99.99% certain that the current behavior is the intended behavior and will always be the behavior. I'm trying to verify that on the D newsgroup though.